# Doubts regarding the below MakeFile

Tags: makefile, nmake

I am new to nmake. I came across this Makefile for nmake. This is a legacy part of application that i need to support. This is working fine, its just that i had problems in understanding the syntax. I tried my best on google but still couldn't understand some intricacies.

I am curious about the concept of using 2 colons in the :INSTALL: rule below. Also not able to get the :B:S variable editing.

```
JAVA_FILES = \
    Abc.java  \
    Def.java \
    Ghi.java


/***********Define targets **********************/
.all : $(JAVA_FILES:B:S=.class)

:INSTALL: .all

$(JAVA_FILES:B:S=.class) : $(JAVA_FILES) .JOINT
for node in `echo $VPATH | tr ':' ' '`
do
    nodecp=${nodecp}:${node}/gfp_scom:${node}/gfp_scom/lib/GfpScomWsdl.jar:${node}/gfp_scom/lib/jmxtools.jar
done
$(JAVAC) -cp ${nodecp}:$(CLASSPATH) -d ../../ $(*:M!=\.class)
```

Comment: your question is lacking focus. Can you rephrase it into something specific about the makefile?

Comment: You need to ask an actual question. If the example makefile doesn't work, you need to state what it should be doing, and exactly what it's doing instead.

Comment: So you're aware: `nmake` is not at all the same syntax as traditional `make`.  You won't be able to answer your questions by reading information about `make`.  You must find and read documentation specifically about `nmake` (and you should probably remove the `make` tags from your question as they're not relevant).

Comment: Thanks for the information that nmake differs a lot from make. I got the nmake reference and going through it. Should be able to figure it out.